# SharePoint 2010 create SPWeb object in synchronous and in asynchronous events

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, event-receivers

Is there any difference in creating SPWeb objects in synchronous and in asynchronous events? A far as I know in both cases it will be

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://........."))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["Tasks"];
        ...... 
    }
}
```

Some one asked this question in interview to one of my friend.

Is there hidden answer for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Other than the intrinsic behavior of synchronous vs. asynchronous, no.  If the same code to open the SPWeb object, there would be no difference.